# Division to output calculation value

Tags: sql

Is there a different way in which I can wrap or write the calculation in the query below so that it divides properly besides using round (100.0 * ...) ?

```
 SELECT ROUND(100.0 * COUNT(DISTINCT c.user_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT b.user_id)) AS browse_to_checkout_percent
```

Thanks!

Comment: 'divides properly ' - means?

Comment: to get an answer that gives output as 23.0 or 20.0

Comment: You won't get any output at all from this query since neither c or b are invoked..

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Your question also doesn't make sense.  I am confident that *all* databases "divide properly".  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming what you mean by not dividing properly is the fact you're getting unexpected results due to dividing integers.  When SQL does math on integers it returns an integer as a result.  This means any decimal result is cut off.

So take the query

```
SELECT 50/100
```

You would expect a result of 0.5 however since .5 is not an integer you get a result of 0

Likewise with

```
SELECT 101/100
```

You would expect a result of 1.01 but you get a result of 1.

COUNT returns an integer so when you do division between the two integers the result is the same as above.

What you need to do with your query is to cast or convert what count returns as another data type.  Which datatype you choose depends on a few factors but for what you are doing I would say float will do.

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT c.user_id) as FLOAT) / CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT b.user_id) as FLOAT) AS browse_to_checkout_percent
```

For simplicity I've removed ROUND but you can add that in as needed.

For more info you can [see this blog post.](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/26/sql-server-division-by-float/)